# PHP Date -1 month today not working

Tags: php

Im having a problem with php date subtracting 1 month in the current date

i got this code.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 month"));

echo $date;
```

with a result of this? am i missing something.

```
2016-03-01 23:21:20
```

Comment: You're making assumtions about what today -1 month should be; today is 30th March; there isn't a 30th February, so what would you expect

Answer (score 4):

Today is March 30. 1 month ago was February 30. But February only had 29 days this year, so February 30 is the same as March 1.

You'll run into the problem on the following days, because that day of the month doesn't exist in the previous month:

- March 29 (in non-leap years)
- March 30-31
- May 31
- July 31
- October 31
- December 31

Comment: so it is a problem when the month is march ,

Comment: It's a problem whenever the current month is longer than the previous month, and you use it on the days that don't exist in the shorter month.

Comment: You'll run into the same problem on May 31.

Comment: This php function is not intelligent as the database functions, e.g. in mysql `select now() - interval '1' month` today (march 31) will evaluate to feb 28 .

Answer (score 0):

If you go back one month from 2016-03-30, you get 2016-02-30. However, 2016-02-29 was the last day of February, so it resolves that date to mean 2016-03-01.